# pep.js on relative positioned DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I am working with pep.js that allows me to drag&drop freely some DIV's.

http://pep.briangonzalez.org/

It works perfect for absolute positioned DIV's as it adds "position:absolute;" as style="(…)" to the DIV's that pep.js is applied on.

But when I want to position the DIV's relative, pep.js overrides their styles to ":absolute".

The way I want to have it:
https://jsfiddle.net/r7y8g4do/2/

What happens when pep.js is applied:
https://jsfiddle.net/r7y8g4do/

this is my pep.js call:

```
$( ".drag" ).pep({


 start: function(e,a) {
        a.$el.addClass('color');
        a.$el.next(".text").fadeIn("slow");


    },
stop: function(e, a) {
        a.$el.removeClass('color');
        a.$el.next(".text").fadeOut("slow");
    }
```

I tried to wrap the .pep function into a .mousedown function, to let it work only when the DIV is clicked – but I could not achieve exactly what I want: In that case I need to click twice to get the dragging.

Does someone have an idea how I can write the script to keep my relative positioning… Or to keep it until pep.js starts working (onmousedown)?

I looked at the docs in github – but could not find something that can help me (or did not understand it right, i am a rookie).

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

Solved it! See my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r7y8g4do/6/

Comment: I found a way using the ThrowPropsPlugin.min.js by GreenSock, but unfortunately that's free for use…

http://codepen.io/Cyrill/pen/yJRZmA?editors=1111

…any possibility to do it with pep.js?

Comment: Same issue. Switching back to JQuery UI I guess...